# Post Doc recommendation letters sent but no response

Tags: advisor, postdocs, recommendation-letter

I have three letters of recommendation sent to a potential post doc employer but when I asked if my recommendation is completed, I did not receive any response from him and it has been a week. Before that, the post doc lab head told me that once he received my letters, he will arrange an on site interview for me. He was also quick to response to my email and showed great enthusiasm before sending out the letters to him.

Does that suggest something wrong with the letters that raise concern? Does that mean I'm out of the game or should I follow up with him? I may be impatient but as indicated in my previous question, my relationship with my advisor was not good and he had submitted a letter drafted by myself.

Very worry. Thank you for advice.

Update: Nevermind, just got interviewed and offered at other top ones.

Comment: Professors have a habit of forgetting to respond to emails. It's not rude to send a follow-up email at this point asking again.

Comment: In my experience, if application materials were sent directly to researchers it is a pleasant surprise if any response is received at all.